# Graph API Photo scheduled_publish_time update

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I want to be able to update the scheduled time of a photo post in a page via the graph API.

The post was initially created using the following API call:

```
$response = $facebook->post('/'.$idToPublish.'/photos', 
array(  'url' => $url, 
                    'published' => false,
                    'scheduled_publish_time' => $scheduledTimestamp,
                    'caption' => $text,
                    'access_token' => $page['accessToken']));
```

Everything is created correctly, but when it comes to update, I'm using the following call:

```
    $response = $facebook->post('/'.$postID, 
                array('scheduled_publish_time' => $newScheduledTimestamp,                           
                      'access_token' => $pageToken ));
```

And I always get Graph returned an error: (#100) Invalid parameter error.

Error goes away as soon as I take out the parameter 'scheduled_publish_time'.

Any thoughts on this one? According to Graph API docs we should be able to update the scheduled time on a post just by sending a new unix timestamp to the published photo ID.

Thanks

Comment: You should consider reporting this as bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs, referencing specific ids.